# Is there a way to block only the main domain in Nginx referrer but not the paths

Tags: nginx, http-referer

I need to know if there is a way to block only the main domain as the referrer url's in Nginx. Like i want to block request with
`referrerurl: www.example.com` but not if the request is from `referrerurl:www.example.com/page1/file1`
I am not sure if there is a way to do it or if i would need a third party module, so any advice would be greatly helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http_referer` variable or `valid_referers` directive combined with `$invalid_referer` variable as stated in NGINX documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html.